# Выбор свободной даты и времени в форме Django

Tags: python, django, django-model

Мне нужно сделать форму с записью на услугу. Нужно чтобы было поле с выбором даты и времени, но должны быть доступны только свободные. То есть в бд есть таблица с записями и назначенными датами, если дата и время заняты, то в форме они не должны быть доступны. Как это реализовать, куда копать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.